# Altering eth1 MAC address

Tags: linux-kernel, ethernet, u-boot, mac-address

I need to alter the MAC address for eth1 ethernet device on my embedded system permanently so it retains this MAC address on every boot.

The OS I'm using:

```
VERSION_ID="v2015.12"
NAME="Angstrom"
ID="angstrom"
PRETTY_NAME="The Ångström Distribution v2015.12"
ANSI_COLOR="1;35"
HOME_URL="http://www.angstrom-distribution.org"
```

The version of Linux I am using is:

```
Linux arria10 4.1.33-ltsi-altera #1 SMP Mon Oct 30 10:14:22 PDT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I am able to set the MAC address for eth0 by altering the following bootarg:

```
setenv ethaddr 00:11:22:33:44:55
save
run bootcmd
```

Once booted, eth0 takes this MAC address as expected.

When I try to do the same for eth1, using `eth1addr` a random MAC address is defined when I boot.

I can however alter the MAC address of eth1 once booted by using the following:

```
ifconfig eth1 down
ifconfig eth1 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:56
ifconfig eth1 up
```

This is not a permanent solution for me as I would need to set the MAC every time I have booted the device.

Is there a way to set the MAC address of eth1 from the bootargs? Also any ideas on why I wouldn't be able to set the MAC address using `setenv eth1addr`?

Edit:
eth0 is RGMII, eth1 is SGMII

Comment: try `systemd-udevd`

Comment: @DDS This facility is not available to me on this version of Linux. Version is Linux arria10 4.1.33-ltsi-altera #1 SMP Mon Oct 30 10:14:22 PDT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: What about udev rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` or is this also not possible due to the previous comment?

Comment: @eblock Is this a file I have to create myself? Do you have a template?

Comment: The purported duplicate question is specific to Debian and Debian-derived operating systems.  _This_ question has not actually specified an operating system.  (No, specifying the kernel is not enough.)

Comment: From my example (a openSUSE VM) it's a rule created by udev:
`rpm -qf /usr/lib/udev/write_net_rules 
udev-228-150.58.1.x86_64`

The rule looks like this:
`SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="virtio-pci", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", KERNELS=="0000:00:03.0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"`

Answer (score 0):

Don't have an angstrom box at reach, but IIRC you can set this in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp # or whatever setting you need for eth1
hwaddress ether 00:11:22:33:44:56
```

Comment: Thanks @isalgueiro, unfortunately this didn't work.

Comment: Do I need to add pre-up and pre-down functionality?

Comment: It should work without pre-up or -down. Sorry to hear that it didn't work for you